# Operator monotone functions inequality under positive contractive maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I was reading some notes from [Wolf](https://www-m5.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M5/Allgemeines/MichaelWolf/QChannelLecture.pdf) and stumbled across this theorem [page 83, theorem 5.13]:

> Let $f$ be an operator monotone function on an interval $I=[0,a]$ with $f(0) \ge 0$ and $T: \mathcal{M}_d \to \mathcal{M}_{d'}$ any positive map for which $T(1) \le 1$, where $\mathcal{M}_d$ is the algebra of $d \times d$ matrices. Then for all $A=A^{\dagger}$ with $\text{spec}(A) \subset I$ we have 
>   \begin{equation}
>  T(f(A))\le f(T(A))
> \end{equation}

Later, in the subsequent corollary 5.2 it is stated that using this theorem we can prove that for any positive $T$ with $T(1)\le 1$

> \begin{equation}
> T(\log(A)) \le \log(T(A)) \quad \text{for } A > 0
> \end{equation}

My problem is that $\log$ doesn't satisfy of course the condition $f(0) \ge 0$ which is fundamental in proving the above theorem. What am i missing?

Edit: for better clarification, the problem is that the proof of the theorem uses the fact that for every op. concave $f$ (op. monotone $\implies$ op. concave) and for every operator $X$ such that $||X|| \le 1$, we have
\begin{equation}
f(X^{\dagger} A X + W^{\dagger} B W) \ge X^{\dagger} f(A) X + W^{\dagger} f(B) W
\end{equation}
where $A,B$ are hermitian and $X^{\dagger} X + W^{\dagger} W=1$. By taking $B=0$ and using $f(0) \ge 0$ we get $f(X^{\dagger}A X) \ge X^{\dagger} f(A) X$ which is what is used for the theorem above. I don't really see how one could circumvent this requirement in order to allow the logarithm.

Comment: I haven't looked at it closely but it sort of seems like it's a typo, since the result with logs follows from your theorem by choosing $f = \exp$, but with the inequality reversed.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong isn't the exponential _not_ operator monotone? In the same book, page 80, it is stated that the exponential is not operator monotone due to the fact that every op. monotone function has an analytic extension on the upper half-plane of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Is the assumption not that we have convexity? If not then I apologize.

Comment: OK, I see that I am mistaken.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong i edited the post for better clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the initial observation to the function $f=\log(x+1)$ to get an inequality for this function. Then use the fact that $\log(x+\epsilon)=[\log((x/\epsilon)+1)+\log(\epsilon)]$ to show that the inequality holds for $\log(x+\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon>0$. Then take the infimum over $\epsilon>0$.